# Representation of the C*-algebra of a Kähler manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, mathematical-physics, c-star-algebras, kahler-manifolds

This question is inspired from mathematics of quantum mechanics.

In quantum mechanics, we start with a Kähler manifold $\mathcal{M}$ (which is $\mathbb{CP}^n$), with the symplectic form $\omega$ and metric $g$.

We have a correspondence between the geometric data and algebraic data as follows. The symplectic form induces a Poisson algebra on the functions $x,y$ on the manifold
$$[x,y] := \omega (dx,dy)\,,$$
and the metric induces a Jordan algebra
$$x\cdot y := g(dx,dy)+xy\,.$$
Or, we can treat the two structures at the same time and say that the Kähler structure (metric+symplectic) induces a  C*-algebra (Poisson+Jordan).

What seems remarkable to me is the representation of the C*-algebra. The representation is a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ by GNS construction. Magically, its projective space turns out to be the manifold we started with: $$\mathbb{P}\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{M}.$$

Somehow, we go back from algebraic data to geometric data by an application of representation theory. Why is this true for $\mathcal M=\mathbb{CP}^n$? Is it true for any Kähler manifold $\mathcal{M}$? Answers and references are both appreciated.

Comment: there is also a tag "c-star-algebras". But if you want to use it, you have to sacrifice one of the already assigned tags.

Comment: Thanks, I added the tag.

Comment: This construction, by definition, outputs a projective space, so if $M$ is not a projective space then it can't output $M$ again. Also, the GNS construction requires as input a state; what state are you using here?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan 1) That is true, as output we always get a projective space. What I'm wondering is if I start from a Kähler space $M$ that is not a projective space, it seems as if the geometric data of $M$ should somehow be related to what we get from $\mathbb P \mathcal{H}$. A correct phrasing for my question seems to be "How does the Kähler geometry of $M$ manifested in $\mathbb{P}\mathcal{H}$", but I also wonder if there is another construction generalizing GNS so that the output space is the same.

Comment: 2) As input state, it does not seem problematic to me to choose an arbitrary point $p\in M$ and then define the state as the linear functional $\rho$ evaluating the function at that point as $\rho(f)=f(p)$.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but might be interesting: for a polarized Kähler manifold $L\to X$ with $\omega\in\mathrm{c}_1(L)$ positive, one can consider for large $k$ the embeddings $X\to\mathbb{P}\left(H^0(X,L^k)\right)$ induced by sections of $L^k$. The manifold thus gets imbedded in some (large) projective space. This seems to be quite different from the construction you are interested in, but might be related somehow.